# Struggling to pass an index of an array as props to another component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, parent-child, react-props

I am trying to build an app in which a user can add a card to an array of cards, then switch the positions of a specific card with the card to the left or right. I wrote a function that I believe will switch a card with that on the left, but I am struggling to debug it because it seems that the index of the chosen card is not properly being passed down to the child component.
Here is my code so far:

`CardList.js` is what is attempting to pass the moveLeft method to `cardItem`

```
import React from "react";
import CardItem from "./CardItem";
import CardForm from "./CardForm";
import './Card.css';

class CardList extends React.Component {
  
    state = {
      cards: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`cards`)) || []
      // when the component mounts, read from localStorage and set/initialize the state
    };
  

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { // persist state changes to longer term storage when it's updated
      localStorage.setItem(
        `cards`,
        JSON.stringify(this.state.cards)
      );
  }

  render() {
    const cards = this.getCards();
    const cardNodes = (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>{cards}</div>
    );

    return (
     <div>
     <CardForm addCard={this.addCard.bind(this)} /> 
     <div className="container">
     <div className="card-collection">
          {cardNodes} 
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addCard(name) {
    const card = {
      name
    };
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards.concat([card])
    }); // new array references help React stay fast, so concat works better than push here.
  }
  
  
  removeCard(index) {
    this.state.cards.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards.filter(i => i !== index)
    })
  }

  moveLeft(index, card) {
    this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
        return {cards: prevState.cards.map(( c, i)=> {
            // also handle case when index == 0
            if (i === index) {
                return prevState.cards[index - 1];
            } else if (i === index - 1) {
                return prevState.cards[index];
            }    
        })};
    }); 
 }

  //moveRight(index, card) {
   // ?
 // }

  getCards() {
    return this.state.cards.map((card) => {
      return (
        <CardItem
          card={card}
          index={card.index}
          name={card.name}
          removeCard={this.removeCard.bind(this)}
          moveLeft={this.moveLeft.bind(this)}
        //  moveRight={this.moveRight}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
export default CardList;
```

`cardItem` is struggling to find the index of the necessary card even though I passed that in as props. I am getting an error saying "×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined" originating from my CardList component.

```
import React from 'react';

import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

class CardItem extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
 <Card style={{ width: '15rem'}}>
  <Card.Header as="h5">{this.props.name}</Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Remove</Button>
  </Card.Body>
  <Card.Footer style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <i class="arrow left icon" onClick={this.leftClick.bind(this)} style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>
  {/*<i class="arrow right icon" onClick={rightClick(index, card)} style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>*/}
  </Card.Footer>
</Card>
 </div>
    )
  }

handleClick(index) { 
  this.props.removeCard(index)
}

leftClick(index, card) {
this.props.moveLeft(index,card)
}

rightClick(index, card) {
  this.props.moveRight(index, card)
}

}
export default CardItem;
```

How can I best pass down the necessary index as props? Thank you

**Edit #1**
I made an error in my addCard method, I never assigned the index to the card. I have fixed this and added a key property in my map return function but am now getting an error saying "×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
Please see the updated CardList.js below:

```
import React from "react";
import CardItem from "./CardItem";
import CardForm from "./CardForm";
import './Card.css';

class CardList extends React.Component {
  
    state = {
      cards: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`cards`)) || []
      // when the component mounts, read from localStorage and set/initialize the state
    };
  

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { // persist state changes to longer term storage when it's updated
      localStorage.setItem(
        `cards`,
        JSON.stringify(this.state.cards)
      );
  }

  render() {
    const cards = this.getCards();
    const cardNodes = (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>{cards}</div>
    );

    return (
     <div>
     <CardForm addCard={this.addCard.bind(this)} /> 
     <div className="container">
     <div className="card-collection">
          {cardNodes} 
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addCard(name, index) {
    const card = {
      name,
      index
    };
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards.concat([card])
    }); // new array references help React stay fast, so concat works better than push here.
  }
  
  
  removeCard(index) {
    this.state.cards.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({
      cards: this.state.cards.filter(i => i !== index)
    })
  }

  moveLeft(index, card) {
    this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
        return {cards: prevState.cards.map(( c, i)=> {
            // also handle case when index == 0
            if (i === index) {
                return prevState.cards[index - 1];
            } else if (i === index - 1) {
                return prevState.cards[index];
            }    
        })};
    }); 
 }

  //moveRight(index, card) {
   // ?
 // }

  getCards() {
    return this.state.cards.map((card) => {
      return (
        <CardItem
          card={card}
          key={card.index}
          name={card.name}
          removeCard={this.removeCard.bind(this)}
          moveLeft={this.moveLeft.bind(this)}
        //  moveRight={this.moveRight}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
export default CardList;
```

[image: error]

Comment: I do not see where you are setting your `card.index`.  In your `addCard` function you are only passing in the `name`, and you do not have a `key` set on your return `map` function.

Comment: Thank you, I made those changes but am now getting a different error as noted in my edit above

Comment: Are you sure your `concat` functionality is working correctly?  Try `push` and see if that works.

Comment: when i change that to push then try to add a new card i get a different error, saying 'TypeError: this.state.cards.map is not a function'

Comment: try `card?.name` and see if you get anything to show up, you should also be checking the state of your `cards` at the end/beginning of each component, to see where things are going awry.

Comment: try that where?

Comment: Exactly where it shows it is bring in your screenshot

Comment: got it, yeah when i did that then clicked the arrow i then got "×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined". it seems the problem switches between the two

Comment: There seems to be an `undefined` in your `this.state.cards`
Try console logging it at the start of the `render` method.

Comment: There's a couple different snafu's you need to be careful of, like `removeCard(index) {
    this.state.cards.splice(index, 1)`, here you are directly mutating state, which is a big problem.

Have to move on for a while, but my guess is you are overwriting your card state somewhere down the line, and you should use a debugger or some console.logs to keep track of what exactly your card state is doing.

Comment: it seems like you have `undefined` entry in you array. can you make sure local storage is cleared. also add `console.log` in map function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your `addCard` & `removeCard` functions. [State updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) in React, due to which you **should not use `this.state` inside `this.setState`**.

Eg: `addCard` should be as follows:

```
addCard(name, index) {
    let card = {name,index};
    this.setState((prevState, prevProps)=> {
        return prevState.cards.concat(card);
    })
}
```

`removeCard` should be modified likewise. The `splice` should be removed too, as the `filter` does the removing.

```
removeCard(index) {
    this.setState(function(prevState,prevProps) {
        return {cards: prevState.cards.filter(function(card,i) {
            return i != index;
        })};
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am confused on the removeCard edits, I wrote this but it does not work:

Comment: ```removeCard(index) {
  this.state.cards(index, 1)
  this.setState((prevState, prevProps)=> {
    return prevState.cards.filter(i => i !== index);
})
}```

Comment: You have to remove the entire instruction/line that contained the `splice`. 
`this.state.cards(index, 1)` should be removed.

Comment: thanks, I have this now but when i click the remove button nothing happens

Comment: `
removeCard(index) {
  this.setState((prevState, prevProps)=> {
    return prevState.cards.filter(i => i !== index);
})
}`

Comment: The first parameter of `filter` should be `card`. The 2nd parameter is `i` (iteration index). The same is true for most iterating methods `forEach`, `map` & `filter`.

Comment: still getting erros ... like this or another way? `removeCard(card,index) {
  this.setState((prevState, prevProps)=> {
    return prevState.cards.filter( card, index);
})
}`

Comment: There is no callback inside the filter ?! Please refer the `filter` doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter